# Mobile Safari: How to implement a fixed position, scrollable iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, webkit, mobile-safari

Is there a way to implement a fixed position, scrollable iframe in Mobile Safari? I have spent quite a few hours on this problem and I can't seem to find a solution for it.

For non-fixed iframes, it is possible to work around some bugs using the combo of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` and `overflow: auto;`, but I can't find a way to make fixed iframes scrollable in Mobile Safari.

Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vokige/edit?html,css) for this problem.

Tested against iOS 8 on iPad 4 and iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 0):

You should add all positions (top,bottom,left,right) to your fixed iframe:

```
.iframe-wrap {
  background: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;                
}
```

I tried this in a iphome simulator and it works.

Comment: This doesn't work. And the Safari in the iPhone simulator does not behave 100% identical to the real Mobile Safari.